# Does a function call require an expression?

Tags: c++, function, arduino

In the code below I define a function "mody" that I call in line 78.  On compilation I get the error "Expected primary expression before ']' token".  I wonder if this error means that to call a function I must do so in an expression, e.g., "z=mody" or something?  But I just want to go to mody, do what it says and come back.  Or is there some other problem with my call?

```
    /*  BREADBOARD
  Implement program on Arduino + breadboard
*/

// constants 
int foodPin = 2;     // to provide food
int painPin = 3;     // to punish
int ucsPin = 4;      // the UCS
int csPin = 5;       // the CS
int lightPin = 6;    // turn the "light" stim on/off
int thresh = 700;

// variables 
int buttonState = 0; // variable for reading the pushbutton status
boolean lighton = false;
unsigned short int energy = 10000;
int stimulus[11] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

int brain[7][11] = { {0,0,0,0,99,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,99,0,0,0,1,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,99,0,0,1,0},
                     {90,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,-99},
                     {0,90,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,1},
                     {0,0,90,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,1},
                     {0,0,0,90,0,0,0,1,-1,1,1} };

int behavior[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

// define behavioral methods
  void mody (int ix, int brain[][11], int stimulus[])
      { int psp=20;
        int j;
        for(j=7;j<11;j++)
    {if (brain[ix][j] > 0) brain[ix][j]+= stimulus[j] * (99-brain[ix][j])/psp;
     if (brain[ix][j] < 0) brain[ix][j]+= -1*(stimulus[j] * abs(99-brain[ix][j])/psp);}
         return;}

void setup() {
  // initialize the pushbutton pins as an input:
  pinMode(foodPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(painPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ucsPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(csPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(lightPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int ix=0;

} // end void setup

void loop(){
  // decay stimulus vector.  do this and check inputs for ALL stimulii later
  int k;
  for(k=0;k<11;k++)
  {if (stimulus[k] > 1) stimulus[k]-=2; else stimulus[k]=0;}

  //check inputs 
  buttonState = digitalRead(foodPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) stimulus[4] = 9;
  buttonState = digitalRead(painPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) stimulus[5] = 9;
  buttonState = digitalRead(ucsPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) stimulus[6] = 9;
  buttonState = digitalRead(lightPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {stimulus[7] = 9; stimulus[8] = 9;lighton = true;}
      else {stimulus[7] = 0; stimulus[8] = 0;lighton = false;}
  buttonState = digitalRead(ucsPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) stimulus[6] = 9;

// routine to multiply:  behavior=brain * stimulus'
int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {  behavior[i]=0;
       for (j=0;j<11;j++)
           {behavior[i]= behavior[i]+stimulus[j]*brain[i][j]; }
    } // end for i
    if (behavior[0] > thresh) {Serial.println("Positive Fixer");}
    if (behavior[1] > thresh) {Serial.println("Negative Fixer");}
    if (behavior[2] > thresh) {Serial.println("UCR"); mody (2, brain[][], stimulus[]);}
    if (behavior[3] > thresh) {Serial.println("Operant one");}
    if (behavior[4] > thresh) {Serial.println("Operant two");}
    if (behavior[5] > thresh) {Serial.println("Operant three");}
    if (behavior[6] > thresh) {Serial.println("Operant four");}

// generate random operant
   if (random(energy) < 10) stimulus[random(4)]= 9 + random(3);

energy --;
Serial.println(energy);

}  // end void loop``
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change :

`mody (2, brain[][], stimulus[]);`

To:

```
mody (2, brain, stimulus);
  //        ^^^    ^^^     Get rid of []
```